# How to optimize model manytomany select?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this code, what I would like to optimizing:

```
articles = Articles.objects.filter(active=True).all().order_by('-added')[start_from:per_page+start_from]
tags = dict()
for article in articles:
    tags[article.id] = Tags.objects.filter(articles=article).all()
```

I think that code would be ok, but they returns error:

```
articles = Articles.objects.filter(active=True).all()[start_from:per_page+start_from]
articles_tags = Tags.objects.filter(articles__in=articles).all()
tags = dict()
for article in articles:
        tags[article.id] = articles_tags.filter(articles=article).all()
```

Error message

```
(1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Django 1.4, try using `prefetch_related` on your QuerySet.  This fetches ManyToMany fields by running a separate query and then marries the two together in Python.  This way you'll retrieve all the data using 2 queries instead of 1 + n queries:

```
# Fetch articles
articles = Articles.objects.filter(active=True) \
    .prefetch_related('tags')[start_from:per_page+start_from]

# Eat a donut
logging.info('omnomnomnom')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related